# How do I render the next page after login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I can't pass the navigation response to the next page after the user correctly fills in the password and email.

I tried passing the navigate from the useNavigation library instead of the answer but when I go to fill in the password or email it doesn't check if the fields are right.

How could I put in place of the response a navigate but checking if the data is right in the database?

```
import "../App.css";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { ErrorMessage, Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import Axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = (values) => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
    }).then((response) => {
      alert(response.data);
      // navigate("/Home")
      // console.log(response);
    });
  };

  const validationsLogin = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email("email inválido")
      .required("O email é obrigatório"),
    password: yup
      .string()
      .min(8, "A senha deve ter pelo menos 8 caracteres")
      .required("A senha é obrigatória"),
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{}}
        onSubmit={handleLogin}
        validationSchema={validationsLogin}
      >
        <Form className="login-form">
          <div className="login-form-group">
            <Field name="email" className="form-field" placeholder="Email" />

            <ErrorMessage
              component="span"
              name="email"
              className="form-error"
            />
          </div>
          {/*Outro campo*/}
          <div className="form-group">
            <Field name="password" className="form-field" placeholder="Senha" />

            <ErrorMessage
              component="span"
              name="password"
              className="form-error"
            />
          </div>

          <button className="button" type="submit">
            Login
          </button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "bd_login_cadastro",
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  db.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?", [email], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    if (result.length == 0) {
      bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
        db.query(
          "INSERT INTO usuarios (email, password) VALUE (?,?)",
          [email, hash],
          (error, response) => {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err);
            }

            res.send({ msg: "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso" });
          }
        );
      });
    } else {
      res.send({ msg: "Email já cadastrado" });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  db.query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?", [email], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          res.send(error);
        }
        if (response) {
          res.send({ msg: "Usuário logado" });
        } else {
          res.send({ msg: "Senha incorreta" });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.send({ msg: "Usuário não registrado!" });
    }
  });
});
```